# Software Update failure

Tags: dual-boot, kernel, updates, settings

I have opened Ubuntu Software and clicked install on OS updates, and after a while it froze and became pressable again. I pressed it and now the colors and gradients of buttons are gone and the icons on Settings are gone. This happened previously, and after I restarted it crashed with an end kernel panic. Should I stay and let Ubuntu run, or should I restart and try for a fix? I'm still in the OS until an answer. Thanks!

Comment: You should stop using that feature in Ubuntu Software. Better to run the first update in terminal. Or search and open Updates.

Comment: So should I just wait and see? The icons came back for the settings, but the ubuntu software doesnt load. I'm hoping for the best.

Comment: In terminal do `sudo apt-get install -f`. Edit and update your question with the error message, if any, except if it says "can't get lock..." or something which means other process is using APT (most likely Ubuntu Software, the software center). Leave it for several minutes more and repeat.

Comment: It actually didnt say anything harmful. Said 0 for everything:
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded."

and yet my ubuntu software is still not loading the "installed" and "updates" pages. any ideas? I don't care that much, I just want to make sure it wont cause any errors when I reboot it

Comment: Do `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` to fully update your system. Reboot and try again. Meanwhile post the error messages if any.

Comment: Alright, I have done what you said and it looks good as new. the Ubuntu Software loads up the installed and updates pages. Updates say `Software up to date` and installed gives the list of installed upgrades.  Thanks! You can write it as an answer and I can choose as the best.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid using Ubuntu Software before installing all the updates suggested after connecting to the internet in the first boot. Run the Updates tools if needed.

Alternatively open the Terminal and proceed with

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

For 16.04 and newer the recommended commands are

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt full-upgrade
```